# How to display date from datetime while retrieving the datetime from database in mvc5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to convert the datetime to date format while retrieving the data from database.

**My Controller Code**

```
public ActionResult GetDates(VisitorsViewModel VisitorsVM)
{
    try
    {
        string sqlcmd = "Select * from View_VisitorsForm where CONVERT(VisitingDate As Date)  >='" + fromdt + "'and CONVERT( VisitingDate As Date) <= '" + todt + "'";

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlcmd, con);
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adp.Fill(dt);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }

    ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();
    rpt.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Areas/Sales/CrystalReports/rpt_VisitSummaryCrystalReport.rpt"));
    rpt.SetDataSource(dt);
    Stream stream = rpt.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);

    return File(stream, "application/pdf");
}
```

I want to convert the date format (need only date not with time) while retrieving from database

How do I convert VisitingDate to display just the date(not time) in below query

```
string sqlcmd = "Select * from View_VisitorsForm where CAST( VisitingDate As Date)  >='" + fromdt + "'and CAST( VisitingDate As Date) <= '" + todt + "'";
```

[image]

The above sql query cant convert the date format, its coming with time. I want only Date . Eg : 12-Mar-16 like this.

Comment: CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),VisitingDate , 1) .. in your select staement

Comment: @ShekharPankaj Time is coming

Answer (score 1):

Use ToString to get only date, suppose you have DateTime type in `date` variable then you can get by this

```
string s = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

if you are using sql server 2008 or higher then you can get only date by `CONVERT(VisitingDate, getdate())`

```
string sqlcmd = "Select * from View_VisitorsForm where CONVERT(VisitingDate, getdate(),110)  >='" + fromdt + "'and CONVERT(VisitingDate, getdate(),110) <= '" + todt + "'";
```

Comment: i want to convert this below query   string sqlcmd = "Select * from View_VisitorsForm where CAST( VisitingDate As Date)  >='" + fromdt + "'and CAST( VisitingDate As Date) <= '" + todt + "'"; not fromDate and Todate . its already converted . i like to change my select query that is like to change the Visiting Date format

Comment: CONVERT(VisitingDate, getdate()) will display time as well.

Comment: @Mostadiz ok i have a try u update comment and let u know

Comment: @RahulMakwana yes it will show the time part but its static for everyone 12:00:00 AM

Comment: @Mostadiz its not working your updated query showing null error(Type VisitingDate is not a defined system type.) this error came

Comment: is VisitingDate is valid datetime type in database ?

Comment: Yes it is datetime only how to check it is valid or not\

Comment: you can get it by database design

Answer (score 0):

in sql you can use `CONVERT()` function in SQL query to do the job.

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),GETDATE())    
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),10)
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),110)
CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),GETDATE(),6)
CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),GETDATE(),106)
CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),GETDATE(),113)
```

Above will result in this :

> Nov 04 2014 11:45 PM
>
> 11-04-14 11-04-2014
>
> 04 Nov 14
>
> 04 Nov 2014
>
> 04 Nov 2014 11:45:34:243

So your query will be :

```
string sqlcmd = "Select Column1,Column2,Column3,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),VisitingDate,110) as 'VisitingDate' from View_VisitorsForm where CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),VisitingDate,110)  >='" + fromdt + "'and CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),VisitingDate,110) <= '" + todt + "'";
```

Here is your problem, you need to select all columns and for the date column do this. so in the query replace Column1,column2 with your column names.

See w3Schools tutorial [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp)

Comment: I want to change the sql query in fron end

Comment: Yes i have a check and try

Comment: Same answer onlly Mostafiz gave but it showing null(Type VisitingDate is not a defined system type.) error

Comment: Time coming @rahul Makwana it coming same as like which is mention in the imge

Comment: sorry for stupid mistake, I realized you are not converting the date while selecting it , updated query converts it when we do a select on the view.